# Failed prop type: The prop `message` is marked as required in `Description`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have following code in my index.jsx for main page

```
toggleDescription(product, success = true) {
    if (success) {
      this.descriptionText = t('products/product_description', {
        name: item.product,
      });
    this.setState({
      open: !open
      failure: !success
   });
}
---some code here---

return (
  <div>
  </Description
  isOpen={this.state.open}
  onRequestClose={this.toggleDescription}
  message={this.descriptionText}
  isError={failure}
  >
  <div> --delete and close buttons here-- </div>
  </Description>
```

I have translation for descriptionText. I am toggling description component. when i first time load the app i get the error in title since description text is undefined. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option is that you can set `this.descriptionText` to a default value like an empty string or something on `constructor`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.descriptionText = 'some default value or empty string';
}
```

or you can use it like below,

```
message={this.descriptionText || 'some default value or empty string'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't save values directly to the component.  The children will not be guaranteed to re-render unless the values are managed by the state.

You ought to change this as such;

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
        descriptionText: 'default text'
    }
},

toggleDescription(product, success = true) {
    if (success) {
      this.setState({
          descriptionText: t('products/product_description', {
              name: item.product,
          }),
          open: !open,
          failure: !success
      });
},

render() {
    return (
  <div>
  </Description
  isOpen={this.state.open}
  onRequestClose={this.state.toggleDescription}
  message={this.state.descriptionText}
  isError={failure}
  >
  <div> --delete and close buttons here-- </div>
  </Description>
```